# Sending my android downloaded log to SIEM

Tags: graylog, nxlog

I am using nxlog to my Graylog server. I am not sure if I did it correctly for my nxlog.conf.
I want to send my  downloaded android log to Graylog.
I able to add in my windows log into my Graylogserver, however, I unable to see any of my android log in the Graylog.
Would anyone help me to check if I did it correctly.

```
   

     #NoFreeOnExit TRUE
        
        define ROOT     C:\Program Files\nxlog
        define CERTDIR  %ROOT%\cert
        define CONFDIR  %ROOT%\conf\nxlog.d
        define LOGDIR   %ROOT%\data
        
        include %CONFDIR%\\*.conf
        
        define LOGFILE  %LOGDIR%\nxlog.log
        
        # Define the log file at the root level
        LogFile %LOGFILE%
        
        Moduledir %ROOT%\modules
        CacheDir  %ROOT%\data
        Pidfile   %ROOT%\data\nxlog.pid
        SpoolDir  %ROOT%\data
        
        <Extension _syslog>
        Module      xm_syslog
        </Extension>
        
        <Extension _charconv>
        Module      xm_charconv
        AutodetectCharsets iso8859-2, utf-8, utf-16, utf-32
        </Extension>
        
        <Extension _exec>
        Module      xm_exec
        </Extension>
        
        <Extension _fileop>
        Module      xm_fileop
        
        # Check the size of our log file hourly, rotate if larger than 5MB
        <Schedule>
        
        Every   1 hour
        Exec    if (file_exists('%LOGFILE%') and \
        (file_size('%LOGFILE%') >= 5M)) file_cycle('%LOGFILE%', 8);
        </Schedule>
        
        # Rotate our log file every week on Sunday at midnight
        <Schedule>
        
        When    u/weekly
        Exec    if file_exists('%LOGFILE%') file_cycle('%LOGFILE%', 8);
        </Schedule>
        
        </Extension>
        
        
        <Extnsion _gelf>
        Module      xm_gelf
        </Extension>
        
        # Snare compatible example configuration
        # Collecting event log
        <Input In_Security>
        Module      im_msvistalog
        <QueryXML>
        
        <QueryList>
        
        <Query Id="0" Path="Security">
        
        <Select Path="Security">*</Select>
        </Query>
        
        </QueryList>
        
        </QueryXML>
        
         </Input>
        
        <Input In_System>
        Module      im_msvistalog
        <QueryXML>
        
        <QueryList>
        
        <Query Id="1" Path="System">
        
        <Select Path="System">*</Select>
        </Query>
        
        </QueryList>
        
        </QueryXML>
        
         </Input>
        
        <Input In_Setup>
        Module      im_msvistalog
        <QueryXML>
        
        <QueryList>
        
        <Query Id="2" Path="Setup">
        
        <Select Path="Setup">*</Select>
        </Query>
        
        </QueryList>
        
        </QueryXML>
        
         </Input>
        
        <Input In_Android_Log>
        Module      im_file
        File        "E:\Andriod Log\phone1.txt"
        SavePos     TRUE
        </Input>
        
        # Converting events to Snare format and sending them out over TCP syslog
        <Output graylog_security>
        Module      om_udp
        Host         192.168.1.xxx
        Port        12201
        OutputType  GELF
        </Output>
        
        <Output graylog_System>
        Module      om_udp
        Host        192.168.1.xxx
        Port        12201
        OutputType  GELF
        </Output>
        
        <Output graylog_Setup>
        Module      om_udp
        Host         192.168.1.xxx
        Port        12201
        OutputType  GELF
        </Output>
        
        <Output graylog_android>
        Module      om_tcp
        Host        192.168.1.xxx
        Port        12201
        OutputType  GELF
        </Output>
        
        # Connect input 'in' to output 'graylog'
        <Route 1>
        Path In_Security => graylog_security
        </Route>
        
        <Route 2>
        Path In_System => graylog_System
        </Route>
        
        <Route 3>
        Path In_Setup => graylog_Setup
        </Route>
        
        <Route 4>
        Path In_Android_Log => graylog_android
        </Route>
```